# Injecting custom HTTP headers to fluentbit

Tags: plugins, fluent, fluent-bit

I am planning to use Fluent Bit to upload certain log information to my custom HTTP endpoint. My endpoint requires a custom authentication header, which needs to be calculated based on the body content. Therefore, I cannot use a static header value. I want to use the `http` output plugin in Fluent Bit and avoid writing my own output plugin. Is there a way to achieve this besides writing my own plugin?